# My react-admin bundle size is huge (860KB)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux, material-ui, react-admin

I already tried to configure various different optimization methods, but my react-admin bundle size stays huge, at 860KB.

What can I do about it? Is it normal? What can be a possible cause? I will post links with my webpack configs in a minute.

I don't think there's any clever way to do code-splitting for now. I have implemented few resources and they should always be used kind of together.

Link to my common webpack config:
https://pastebin.com/t6uMWiJ6

```js
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: './src/components/index.js'
  },

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'static/js/[name].[contenthash:8].js'
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          cacheDirectory: true,
          cacheCompression: false,
          babelrc: true
        }
      },
      { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader' },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        exclude: [/\.(js|jsx)$/, /.html$/, /.css$/, /.json$/],
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: 'static/media/[name].[contenthash:8].[ext]'
        }
      }
    ]
  },

  resolve: {
    unsafeCache: true,
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json', '.css'],
    alias: {
      actions: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/actions'),
      reducers: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/reducers'),
      components: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/components'),
      lib: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/components/_lib'),
      styles: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/styles'),
      config: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/config')
    }
  },

  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/public/index.html',
      favicon: './src/public/favicon.ico'
    }),
    new webpack.PrefetchPlugin('react'),
    new webpack.PrefetchPlugin('react-dom')
  ],

  optimization: {
    usedExports: true
  }
};
```

Here are my dependencies

```js
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.9.2",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.13",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "next",
    "connected-react-router": "^6.8.0",
    "final-form": "^4.19.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "moment": "^2.25.3",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "ra-core": "^3.5.0",
    "ra-data-simple-rest": "^3.2.2",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-admin": "^3.1.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-final-form": "^6.4.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "react-router": "^5.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.6",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.9.4",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.5.2",
    "file-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.3.0",
    "style-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "webpack": "next",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.7.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "^2.2.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.2.2"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "history": "^4.10.1",
    "immutable": "^4.0.0-rc.12",
    "seamless-immutable": "^73.1.4"
  },
  "sideEffects": [
    "*.css"
  ]
}
```

Comment: 860k is not huge

Comment: This makes me feel more at ease. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Tree shaking is probably what you need to look at. See https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/

Note, as they say above, the way you import your modules in your source code is lso important here.

In essence though, it should enable webpack to just bundle the parts of npm packages that are needed.

Comment: Worth noting this only applies in production so don't be worried when you see a big package in dev. This is handled when you set Webpack's "mode"

Comment: Sure, 860KB is in production, 5MB for dev. I tried to configure tree-shaking, but it doesn't seem like its working (I make proper use of import statements and set optimization.usedExports to true). Maybe some package that I use isn't helping. Anyways thanks for the help.

Comment: No worries + good luck! Tools like https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer can help shed light on things like this too.